# How to bake texture in the background with multiprocessing or subprocess and bring the baked texture back into the current scene?

Tags: python, texture-baking

I want to bake the texture in the background and bring the baked texture back into the current `scene` so that blender doesn't freeze while baking.

Answer (score 1):

Not an optimal solution but you could open two instances of Blender.

In the one instance you do the baking stuff and in the other you use the Image.

You could link some objects from the baking file to the Image View file so you have the same setup. And if the baking is finished you go into the outliner of the viewing file and reload the library(baking file) with right click onto it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think not freezing while baking is possible. because it is essentialy "rendering". While we can "uncheck" the lock interface in normal rendering, i dont think we can unlock in the baking one.

[image]

**but i have a little recommendation.** I've been using this amazing baking addon named "simplebake",to export mesh and textures to unreal engine. which really makes my baking workflow much much faster.
Also simplebake has the feature you wanted, which is automatically apply the baked texture and mesh right back to the scene while maintaining the old baked geometry in a hidden collection.

> bring the baked texture back into the current scene

the developer is quite responsive and hears what we want. Once i requested to add a USD output and he added it in an instant.

here is the link: https://www.blendermarket.com/products/simplebake---simple-pbr-and-other-baking-in-blender-2

i hope my answer helps you

Comment: Absolutely awesome addon! This should become a part of Blender!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that could work.
In the experimental features you have the option "Draw Manager Locking". It says it Doesnt look the UI during background rendering
[image]